# Working with Bootstrap 4 and Sass (and Bower)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm learning to use Sass (never used a CSS pre-processor before), and I'm wondering how to use it with Bootstrap 4 properly.

Should I include in my header.php files the bootstrap.min.css? Then when I need to use a Sass mixin or some variable, do I include it in my .scss file?

OR

Should I include all of bootstrap.scss in my styles.scss, then compile it to one style.css and only include that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a main file (a Sass manifest) where you import your Sass variables, mixins and partials as well as the Bootstrap library. After that's in place Sass will automatically output a CSS file you can include on your header.php file.

**Gotchas**

- Import only the bits you need from Bootstrap (instead of the whole library). Here's a [handly list where you can see the components you can choose from](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss).
- Make sure to create [variables.scss file based on the template Bootstrap provides](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss).
- Make sure to import the variables file **before** the Bootstrap library so it takes effect.
- Use Sass in watch mode on development

Comment: > Import only the bits you need from Bootstrap (instead of the whole library). Here's a handly list where you can see the components you can choose from.

What if I want the whole bootstrap formatting?

Comment: Then there's no customization to be done, just use it as is.